# 'if' statement on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to write a simple `if` statement. I want to check in what community the current user is. I wrote this:

```
<p>{! IF( {! $Network.Name }==partners,
 'Yep', 'Nope') }</p>
```

But I am getting syntax errors the whole time.

How do I correct this?

Comment: What is "VFP"? Just VF, Visualforce?

Comment: @Ant -check answer reminder (if any of the below answers helped resolve your question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use redundant merge syntax. Once you are within the merge, no further curly braces (`{}`) are required.

```
{!IF({!condition}, truthy_value, falsy_value}
<!-- ^^         ^ these are your problem  -->
```

Instead:

```
{!IF(condition, truthy_value, falsy_value)}
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is the correct syntax

```
{! IF( $Network.Name=='partners', 'Yep', 'Nope') }
```